# Sending Large file after converting to json to Action in MVC controller

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-2, httpwebrequest, large-files

I am reading a file in bytes using `ReadAllBytes()` method. Then convert these bytes to base64. Then send this base64 string as a part of JSON. On server side (which is MVC action) I receive the JSON and convert the base64 into bytes and then save it.
Small files in KB are transferring very fast and saving in temp folder. But the files in MB is not transferring at all.

I have set `maxrequestlength`, execution timeout done every thing with web config and even test by using `httpwebrequest.keepalive = true` and `false`.... but still all in vain. I can't send file chunks because its not the requirement. Want to send a Complete file at once...

```
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes("D://test.pdf");

string convert = Convert.ToBase64String(b);

Customer cs = new Customer();

cs.JsonString = convert;

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

string json = js.Serialize(cs);

var request (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:46360/Home/Tester");

request.Method = "POST";

request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

request.ContentLength = (json.Length);

request.KeepAlive = false;

request.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;

request.Accept = "Accept=application/json";

request.SendChunked = false;

request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))

{
  streamWriter.Write(json);
  streamWriter.Close();
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
  var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```